# How to not index nested collection but still store in Elasticsearch using NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Is there a way in NEST to skip a nested collection or type from being indexed, but still include with the document?

I can use below to completely skip the property, not just from being indexed:

```
[ElasticProperty(OptOut=true)]
public List<MyClass> subtype { get; set; }
```

Using Index=FieldIndexOption.no appears to have no effect (the mapping looks the same):

```
[ElasticProperty(Index=FieldIndexOption.no)]
public List<MyClass> subtype { get; set; }
```

I want to avoid specify the FieldIndexOption.no on each property of the nest type.  Is there a another way?

**Edit 1:**

Code for creating the index:

```
elasticClient.CreateIndex("MyParentClass", new IndexSettings());
elasticClient.MapFromAttributes<MyParentClass>();
```

We're currently on version 0.12 of NEST (upgrade pending).

Comment: would you mind posting your code that's creating your index?

Comment: @GregMarzouka post updated to include code that creates the index